# My code shows no errors but doesn't debug and displays an error in cosole

Tags: java

so here is the error im getting in console

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at Div_mod2.<init>(Div_mod2.java:67)
at Div_mod2$1.run(Div_mod2.java:34)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

And here is my actual code for the program.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Div_mod2 extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Div_mod2 frame = new Div_mod2();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Div_mod2() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 700, 477);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setVisible(true);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);



    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
    textField.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 25));
    textField.setBounds(394, 41, 171, 66);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
    num1 = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
    int division1;
    int division2;
    int mod1,mod2;
    division1 = num1 / num2; 
    division2 = num2 / num1; 
    mod1 = num1 % num2;
    mod2 = num2 % num1;

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Inscrire le premier entier :");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 18));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(25, 38, 325, 66);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lblInscrireLeDeuxime = new JLabel("Inscrire le deuxi\u00E8me entier : ");
    lblInscrireLeDeuxime.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 18));
    lblInscrireLeDeuxime.setBounds(25, 147, 325, 66);
    contentPane.add(lblInscrireLeDeuxime);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
    textField_1.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 25));
    textField_1.setColumns(10);
    textField_1.setBounds(383, 144, 171, 66);
    contentPane.add(textField_1);
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());



    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("a");
    lblNewLabel_1.setVisible(false);
    lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 18));
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(25, 240, 143, 39);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);
    lblNewLabel_1.setText(String.valueOf(num1+" / "+num2+" = "+division1));

    JLabel label_3 = new JLabel("a");
    label_3.setVisible(false);
    label_3.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 18));
    label_3.setBounds(25, 288, 143, 39);
    contentPane.add(label_3);
    label_3.setText(String.valueOf(num1+" / "+num2+" = "+division2));

    JLabel label = new JLabel("a");
    label.setVisible(false);
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 18));
    label.setBounds(25, 388, 143, 39);
    contentPane.add(label);
    label.setText(String.valueOf(num1+" / "+num2+" = "+mod1));

    JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("a");
    label_1.setVisible(false);
    label_1.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 18));
    label_1.setBounds(25, 338, 143, 39);
    contentPane.add(label_1);
    label_1.setText(String.valueOf(num1+" / "+num2+" = "+mod2));

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Division & Modulo");
    btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            lblNewLabel_1.setVisible(true);
            label_1.setVisible(true);
            label_3.setVisible(true);
            label.setVisible(true);

            }
    });
    btnNewButton.setForeground(SystemColor.windowBorder);
    btnNewButton.setBackground(SystemColor.activeCaptionBorder);
    btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 18));
    btnNewButton.setBounds(394, 288, 243, 77);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

}
}
```

im not exactly sure what is the problem and i really need help figuring this out
ive gone through everything over and over got a second pair of eyes to look at it aswell they arent sure about my problem

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me out its greatly appreciated

Comment: This is because of this instruction. Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()); You are calling it inside before your panel is created and visible. Initial value is empty (""). You should move this instruction to some actions listener method.

Answer (score 1):

Stacktrace information should be enough to resolve this. Your hint is this line:

`at Div_mod2.<init>(Div_mod2.java:67)`

During initialization of the Div_mod2 at some point (line 67) you seem to attempt to assign a `String` value to be converted to a number `Integer`. As this seems to be empty (again by the error message of the stacktrace):

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`

The process fails. The reason why your code is not showing any error is that the `NumberFormatException` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html is a RuntimeException (thus requires no try-catch block).

I would suggest some things:

1) Try to figure out the source the invalid `String` value.

2) Read up on what are RuntimeExceptions

3) Read up on how to extract useful information from a stacktrace.

Comment: @AlexAce Happy to help!